# Run grails integration tests in run-app environment

Tags: tomcat, testing, grails, integration, embedded-resource

Is it possible to run Grails integration tests using the same environment as run-app?
In other words in an environment that starts the embedded Tomcat (or another container)?

Comment: naggy, what do you need  with this ?

Comment: Just set the same dataSource?

Comment: What I'm looking for is the ability to have the embedded Tomcat being launched when I run integration tests. Currently that is not the case... I need that to be able to setup a container with full JTA, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Functional** test phase is probably what you are looking for. It starts embedded container so you can test/access application via browser/url.

Grails documentation is not very precise as it says "Grails does not ship with any support for writing functional tests directly, but there are several plugins available for this."

Nevertheless

```
grails test-app functional:
```

works fine and runs everything from "functional" subdirectory with Tomcat/container up.